# Retain a11y focus functionality with ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility

Angular 9 and Angular material

I am wrapping `mat-chip-list` in `foo-chip-list` element. However, I lose the a11y functionality where the arrow function goes to the next chip. Is there anyway to retain that functionality without have to recode what is already coded in mat-chip-list?

Also, would cdk portal instead of ng-content be a way where I could pass in the chip elements and still retain the original mat-chip-list a11y features like the arrow?

foo-chip-list element:

```html
<mat-chip-list
    [aria-orientation]= "ariaOrientation"
    [multiple]="multiple"
    [selectable]="selectable"
    class="atlas-chip-list"
    [ngClass]="{'mat-chip-list-stacked' : ariaOrientation == 'vertical'}">

  <ng-content></ng-content>

</mat-chip-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this, but you'll need to use a `@HostListener` which may impact other parts of your application.

In your `FooChipListComponent`, add the following:

```
@ContentChildren(MatChip, { descendants: true }) chips: QueryList<MatChip>;

_keyManager: FocusKeyManager<MatChip>;

@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
keydown(event: any) {
  this._keyManager.onKeydown(event);
}

ngAfterContentInit() {
  this._keyManager = new FocusKeyManager<MatChip>(this.chips)
    .withWrap()
    .withVerticalOrientation()
    .withHomeAndEnd()
    .withHorizontalOrientation('ltr');
}
```

This uses the `FocusKeyManager` from Material's a11y to setup keyboard focus/navigation on the chips after the `<ng-content>` element has been replaced with the chips. `@ContentChildren` takes care of getting the chips - we need to use ContentChildren rather than ViewChildren as we're using `<ng-content>`.

The `keydown` method passes the keydown event to the `FocusKeyManager` which will take care of the navigation when you press the direction arrow keys.

I've produced a [working StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ylnh8d?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffoo-chip-list.component.ts). If you change the value of `ariaOrientation` to `vertical` in `foo-chip-list.component.ts` you'll see how it works with stacked chips.

**Update:**
After posting the solution above, I spotted a problem. In the demo, click the 3rd chip ("Primary Fish") and press the right arrow. You'll notice that the selection now moves to the first chip rather than the fourth chip. This is because the `activeItemIndex` doesn't get updated when you use the mouse to select. To fix this, I made the following changes in component where I define the chips to be used as ng-content:

```
<foo-chip-list #chipList>
  <mat-chip (click)="selectChip(0)">One fish</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip (click)="selectChip(1)">Two fish</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip (click)="selectChip(2)">Primary fish</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip (click)="selectChip(3)">Accent fish</mat-chip>
</foo-chip-list>
```

and in the Typescript for that component:

```
@ViewChild('chipList') chipList: FooChipList;

selectChip(index: number) {
  this.chipList.updateSelection(index);
}
```

Then in `FooChipList` I added the following method:

```
updateSelection(index: number) {
  this._keyManager.setActiveItem(index);
}
```

This means when a chip is clicked, it updates the active item in the key manager, so keyboard navigation works. Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ylnh8d-u9hdv2?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffoo-chip-list.component.ts) for a demo.